# Broker on Raspberry Pi with Python

Tags: python, zeromq

I'm programming a broker on my Raspberry Pi with Python and I have the sub.js and pub.js programmed in JavaScript. The pub and the sub are tested and work correctly, but the broker code doesn't react.

PUSH.js

```
const{PUSH}= require('./config');
var zmq = require("zeromq"),
 sock = zmq.socket("push");

sock.connect("tcp://"+PUSH);
console.log("PUSH connected to port 24041 from the broker");

setInterval(function() {
  console.log("PUSH sending to broker");
  sock.send("example");//send to broker
}, 500);
```

SUB.js

```
const{sub}= require('./config');
var zmq = require("zeromq"),
  sock = zmq.socket("sub");

sock.connect("tcp://"+ sub);
console.log("sub connected to port 24042 from the broker");
sock.subscribe(""); //term what sub send

sock.on("message", function (msg) {
  //Broker received what pub send
  console.log("Broker has received: %s", msg.toString());
});
```

[Output from working broker sending "example"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N0vpp.png)
[Output from raspberry pi for PUSH.js and PUB.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/te8Qn.png)

With the broker code I want receive and print from PUSH.js (port 41) and send back to SUB.js (port 42).

```py
import zmq

import time

def main():

    """main method"""

    # Prepare our context and publisher
    context   = zmq.Context()
    publisher = context.socket(zmq.PUSH)
    subscriber = context.socket(zmq.SUB)
    publisher.connect("tcp://address:42")
    subscriber.connect("tcp://address:41")
    subscriber.setsockopt(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, b"example")

    while True:
        #print received contents from port 41
        [address, contents] = subscriber.recv_multipart()
        print("[%s] %s" % (address, contents))
        #send received contents from port 42
        publisher.send_multipart([address, contents])

    # We never get here but clean up anyhow
    publisher.close()
    subscriber.close()
    context.term()  
    if __name__ == "__main__":

    main()
```

output broker:
nothing print

Comment: Can you confirm if your indentation in your answer reflects your actual code? It looks like the call to `main()` is within the `main()` function declaration, so please edit your post to reflect what it actually looks like since I couldn't make that assumption for you.

Comment: In what way is the broker supposed to react? The snippet looks to me like a repeater i.e it repeats whats received from subscriber and publishes it on publisher. I would start debugging by making sure that I am receiving the data properly (try printing). You could also just dummy some data internally to see if the publishing is working as well. Also double check your port assignments.

Answer (score 0):

1. make sure the port numbers do match -- `41 != 24041` / `42 != 24042`
2. make sure each link has at least one **`.bind()`**-node and all others `.connect()` to that one address/port, so as to make **both the `PUB/SUB`** and **`PUSH/PULL`** archetypes indeed work together
3. make sure to follow the ZeroMQ published API & avoid incompatible setups, like trying to bond `PUSH/PUSH`.